# How do I expose prop types for a svelte/vite package?

Tags: svelte, vite, sveltekit, npm-package

I am creating a svelte component library, which I want to publish to npm and use in other projects.

The problem: when I import a component from said library, I don't see the available props I can pass to that component, in the same way I would see them if the component came from a local import.

I'm not sure if this is a svelte/vite quesiton or an editor question, but the props appear neither in Intellij, nor in VSCode.

Example image: When I type <Button s... I would like the editor to tell me that I have "size" as a prop I can pass. This happens if Button comes from a local import, but not from my library.

[image]

Edit: The types do exist. I can see them generated alongside each component in the .d.ts files. It's just that they are not picked up by the editor.

Comment: Are you using SvelteKit to create your package?

Comment: Yes. I'm using SvelteKit.

Comment: Show your `package.json`, you need to define type locations there.